# Data won't echo on Highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, highcharts

I can't get my data to plot on the highchart but it shows up on the source, what am I doing wrong? I don't know if I am using the wrong syntax to echo my string from the hcdata.php. I have been having this problem with getting the output to show up on the actual chart from what I can see the data is correctly formatted it comes out like this:

> [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,10,39,36), 20179],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,10,30,00), 20031],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,10,09,36), 19684],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,09,54,36), 19384],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,09,39,36), 19039],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,09,24,36), 18763],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,09,09,36), 18435],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,08,54,36), 18097],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,08,39,36), 17788],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,08,30,00), 17552],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,08,09,36), 17169],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,08,00,00), 16940],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,07,45,00), 16608],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,07,30,00), 16284],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,07,15,00), 15922],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,06,54,36), 15216],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,06,39,36), 14724],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,06,30,00), 14352],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,06,09,36), 13713],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,05,54,36), 13491],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,05,39,36), 13660],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,05,24,36), 13680],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,05,09,36), 13548],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,04,54,36), 13327],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,04,45,00), 13263],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,04,30,00), 13178],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,04,09,36), 13105],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,03,54,36), 13048],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,03,39,36), 13054],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,03,24,36), 13079],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,03,15,00), 13138],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,03,00,00), 13200],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,02,39,36), 13330],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,02,24,36), 13409],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,02,15,00), 13512],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,01,54,36), 13675],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,01,39,36), 13825],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,01,24,36), 13986],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,01,15,00), 14143],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,00,54,36), 13851],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,00,39,36), 14066],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,00,24,36), 14303],
>   [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,00,09,36), 14591]

```
    <?php include "data.php"; ?>
    <?php include "hcdata.php"; ?>


            <!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <html>
        <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="''/SQLPHP/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="''/SQLPHP/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="''/SQLPHP/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    var data = [
                [<?php echo $finalString; ?>]
            ];

    data.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a[0] - b[0];
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Forecast vs Actual Load [VM]'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'This chart displays the time and actual forecast load for this    region'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Actual Load (WM)'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.x) +': '+ this.y +' m';
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Forecast vs Actual Load',
            // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
            // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
            // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
            data: data
            }]
          });
       });


    </script>
   </head>
<body>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP data insert looks like it is wrapping the data in 2 `[]` blocks:

```
var data = [
                [<?php echo $finalString; ?>]
            ];
```

You need to wrap your entire `data` set in one `[]`. Such that it looks like:

```
var data = [
                <?php echo $finalString; ?>
            ];
```

You should end up with this:

```
[
[Date.UTC(2013,05,31,10,39,36), 20179], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,10,30,00), 20031], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,10,09,36), 19684], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,09,54,36), 19384], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,09,39,36), 19039], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,09,24,36), 18763], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,09,09,36), 18435], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,08,54,36), 18097], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,08,39,36), 17788], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,08,30,00), 17552], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,08,09,36), 17169], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,08,00,00), 16940], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,07,45,00), 16608], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,07,30,00), 16284], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,07,15,00), 15922], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,06,54,36), 15216], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,06,39,36), 14724], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,06,30,00), 14352], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,06,09,36), 13713], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,05,54,36), 13491], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,05,39,36), 13660], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,05,24,36), 13680], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,05,09,36), 13548], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,04,54,36), 13327], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,04,45,00), 13263], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,04,30,00), 13178], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,04,09,36), 13105], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,03,54,36), 13048], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,03,39,36), 13054], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,03,24,36), 13079], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,03,15,00), 13138], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,03,00,00), 13200], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,02,39,36), 13330], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,02,24,36), 13409], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,02,15,00), 13512], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,01,54,36), 13675], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,01,39,36), 13825], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,01,24,36), 13986], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,01,15,00), 14143], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,00,54,36), 13851], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,00,39,36), 14066], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,00,24,36), 14303], [Date.UTC(2013,05,31,00,09,36), 14591]
]
```

Comment: aren't they already wrapped in the highcharts coding...$(function () {
    var data = [
                [<?php echo $finalString; ?>]
            ];

Comment: Missed that. Updated answer. Can you console write what your javascript data var is?